# Open form at cursor position, Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am trying to figure out how to position a Form to open at a given mouse location, despite my monitor settings.

In the Form's `OnCreate` event, I have this:

```
procedure TSplashScreen.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
   oMousePos: TPoint;
   nLeft, nTop: Integer;
begin
    Scaled := false;
    PixelsPerInch := Screen.PixelsPerInch;
    Scaled := true;
    //Position:=poScreenCenter;

   //center form for 2nd monitor   //zzz
   if (Screen.MonitorCount > 1) then                             //zzz
   begin
      GetCursorPos(oMousePos);
      if (oMousePos.X > Screen.Width) or (oMousePos.X < 0) then
      begin
         Self.Position := poDesigned;
         nLeft := Screen.Monitors[1].Left + Round(Screen.Monitors[1].Width / 2) - Round(Self.Width / 2);
         nTop := Screen.Monitors[1].Top + Round(Screen.Monitors[1].Height / 2) - Round(Self.Height / 2);
         Self.Left := nLeft;
         Self.Top := nTop;
      end;
   end;
end;
```

When I have 2 monitors, and monitor 1 is set as primary monitor, the Form will open at the mouse cursor.

However, if I set monitor 2 to primary, the Form will always open on monitor 2.

Comment: `Mouse.CursorPos` should already hold the exact location you need without any calculations... Also, what is your form's `Position` set to?

Comment: Loads of strange things here. Messing around with Scaled and PixelsPerInch is really odd. Only looking at cursor position when the display is extended is odd. Testing against Screen.Width and zero is odd. Assuming that monitor number 1 is somehow special is odd. Using floating point rather than integer arithmetic is odd. What are you actually trying to do? As for this code which has so many problems, why did you choose not to debug it? I can't stress how important the skill of debugging is. Please learn it. Don't give up on code when it doesn't behave as expected. Debug.

Comment: "this is called in the initialization section of the main form." I sure hope not. The `initialization` section has no context of the form yet. That section is executed before any forms have even been created.

Comment: @MartynA Indeed, most likely just a poor choice of words, perhaps not knowing there's something else called an "`initialization` section".

Comment: Monitors can be stacked vertical, in which case your horizontal position testing won't mean anything. There can also be more than two monitors, a pointer not on the primary monitor does not mean it's on the second. Give up on your conditions, write one code that would account for any possible position.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to position the Form on the same monitor that the mouse cursor is currently in, use the Win32 API [`MonitorFromPoint()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145062.aspx) function (which is wrapped by the VCL's [`TScreen.MonitorFromPoint()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.MonitorFromPoint) method), eg:

```
procedure TSplashScreen.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  if (Screen.MonitorCount > 1) then
  begin
    r := Screen.MonitorFromPoint(Mouse.CursorPos).WorkareaRect;
    Self.Position := poDesigned;
    Self.Left := r.Left + ((r.Width - Width) div 2);
    Self.Top := r.Top + ((r.Height - Height) div 2);
    { alternatively:
    Self.SetBounds(
      r.Left + ((r.Width - Width) div 2),
      r.Top + ((r.Height - Height) div 2),
      Width, Height);
    }
  end else begin
    Self.Position := poScreenCenter;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Perfect!  and thanks for NOT slamming me on the horrid code I've inherited!